# How to determine if a component in UI has been Updated in Vaadin 8

Tags: java, web-applications, vaadin, vaadin4spring, vaadin8

In an application based on Vaadin 8 I want to implement a Command that remove the value of all fields. I have done this Using Binder. When user is activating the command a new Bean will be created.

```
    @Override public void menuSelected(MenuBar.MenuItem selectedItem) {

    controller.createNewBean();
    Page.getCurrent().reload();

}
```

I want to show a message box to the user  which warns that by proceeding all values for all components will be lost. I am using a TabView and there are relatively many components.
I want to show this message only if user has changed a value for at least one component. 
I wonder if Vaadin has something like `UI.getCurrent().isDirty()` or another mechanism to determine if user has entered a new value to a component?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

The most effective way that I found was to register a new listener to the binder to get notified of any changes in the component value.

In this listener, I use an atomic integer that gets incremented for every change.
Later on, using this atomic integer, I decide if any of the fields have been touched by the user.

Not that, this does not detect changes but it detects the modifications (e.g. the user might change a field value multiple times but set the value to the original value finally).

```
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();
binder.addValueChangeListener((HasValue.ValueChangeListener<Object>) event -> counter.incrementAndGet());
```

Make sure to reset the counter when required (e.g. at the save time).

Comment: Elegant solution! With Vaadin 14.1.23 the generics part is slightly different (at least from what my Eclipse accepts): binder.addValueChangeListener((HasValue.ValueChangeListener<? super ValueChangeEvent<?>>) event -> counter.incrementAndGet());

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use `binder.hasChanges()`. This basically checks whether your fields and the underlying bean bound to the fields differ because of user interactions.

From Vaadin's Docs:

> Check whether any of the bound fields' values have changed since last explicit call to setBean(Object), readBean(Object), removeBean(), writeBean(Object) or writeBeanIfValid(Object).

See [Vaadin's API](https://vaadin.com/api/8.0.1/com/vaadin/data/Binder.html#hasChanges--) and Vaadin Doc's chapter [Binding Data to Forms](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/datamodel/datamodel-forms.html) for more information.

With `Page.getCurrent().reload()` you get a new UI and all your components are reset as if you opened a new tab. For resetting your components I would recommend to use `binder.readBean(theNewBeanWithFreshValues)`. This sets the values of the bound fields back to the values of the bean.

Comment: Thanks @Axel Meier. It seems the only way is binder.hasChanges(). The problem is that I have different Beans and different tabs and I have to be aware of many binders. I am using reload instead of readBrean because of this as well.

Comment: I tested implementation with binder hasChanges. It is not working as described in the documentation. See this: https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/14906891/15007809

Comment: @Govan Thank you for your feedback. Indeed `hasChanges()` makes more sense to use in combination with `readBean()` and `writeBean()`. With `setBean()` the changes are automatically committed `hasChanges()` would return false. Also with `setBean()` there is no way to restore the old values anymore.